How do I turn this elasticsearch query on the xpack users into a Java Client request?
Goal
I'm trying to search for users with a specific prefix.
To that end, I have a query similar to this that works in Kibana:
POST /_security/_query/user
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "username": "first." 
    }
  },
  "search_after": ["first.last0@gmail.com"],
  "size": 1000,
  "sort": [
    { "username": { "order": "asc"} } 
  ]
}

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this xpack query in Java using v8.13.4 of the elasticsearch-java client.
Using client.security.getuser
I've tried using the client.security().getUser().get("first.");, but this only works for exact matches.
I've tried client.security().getUser().result(), but this doesn't filter for the users I want. I'd have to do it in Java.
Using SearchRequest
I've tried Using SearchRequest, but that's giving me a ElasticsearchException: [es/search] failed: [security_exception] action [indices:data/read/search] is unauthorized for user [zs_svc_acct] with effective roles [my_role] on indices [_security/_query/user], this action is granted by the index privileges [read,all]. The my_role role grants the service account manage_security, so it has the necessary permissions, but I'm likely not setting it up correctly.
        // Build the prefix query
        PrefixQuery prefixQuery = new PrefixQuery.Builder()
                .field("username")
                .value("first.")
                .build();

        // Build the search request
        SearchRequest.Builder query = new SearchRequest.Builder()
                .index("_security/_query/user")
                .query(new Query.Builder().prefix(prefixQuery).build())
                .size(1000);

        SearchResponse<User> response = client.search(query.build(), User.class);

From POM:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.13.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.13.4</version>
        </dependency>

